# Why does inheritance seem to be working in an unexpected way?

Tags: php, inheritance

`MApp` uses `$database_object`.  I got an error that I could not use it because it was private.  However I changed it to protected and now it works.  Note that in the class hierarchy MApp is above MAppAMAdder.

I thought that protected meant that child classes could use the resource not parent classes.  Is PHP different from other languages or is my understanding of how inheritance works not correct?

**MAppAdder Snippet**

```
class MAppAMAdder extends MApp
{
    protected $database_object; // private will cause a fail.
```

**MApp**

```
abstract class MApp extends M
{
    protected function getID($pipe)
    {
        $temp = $this->database_object->_pdoQuery('single', 'pull_id_by_h_token',
            array($pipe['server']['smalls']['h_token']));
        $pipe['id'] = $temp['id'];
        return $pipe;
    }
    protected function addTweetTop($pipe, $comment)
    {
        $input = array( $pipe['server']['smalls']['h_token'], 
                        $pipe['server']['smalls']['picture'], 
                        $pipe['server']['smalls']['name'], 
                        $comment, 
                        time(), 
                        $pipe['server']['smalls']['h_file'] );
        $this->database_object->_pdoQuery( 'none', 'tweet_insert', $input);
        return $pipe;
    }
}
```

**Error**

**Fatal error**:  Cannot access private property MAppTweet::$database_object in...

Comment: Can you show more code? According to the PHP manual what you said should be right, protected should be visible for inherited classes.

Comment: `// private will cause a fail.` ... print that error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PHP [`protected`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) means that parent classes can also access the property:

> Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class
>   itself *and by inherited and parent classes*.

You are correct in that this behavior is different from the "classical" behavior of strongly typed languages such as C++ and Java. In such languages (commonly called *statically typed*) the compiler prevents you from accessing class members in a way that is not provably correct by issuing a compile-time error. That's why a parent class cannot speculatively access a member defined in a child class: there is no guarantee that the member will be there at runtime.

On the other hand, PHP is dynamically typed and does let you refer to any member, even ones that do not exist at all (the access results to `null` in that case). The check for the existence of such a member is performed at runtime and can result in a wide array of outcomes (from nothing out of the ordinary to a runtime error in certain cases).

Comment: @pure_code: I missed that part. Yes, it is different. Editing the answer to give some more information.

Answer (score 0):

How can the super class use a field that is only defined in the subclass? That can't work properly. You can access any field of the superclass from within the subclass, as long as it is declared as `public` or `protected`. `private` fields are not accessible for the subclass. The superclass however knows nothing about any subclass that might exist.

Comment: Actually it can and it does work properly. It's also documented.